# Why does Google Fonts half works through Visual Studio?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-font-api

When I created a page using Visual Studio Code, the font was looked good.
When I started to use Visual Studio (Whether it was through debugging or running in azure), part of the text became distorted.

The difference between text that looks good and text that doesn't look good (distorted) is that the text that doesn't look good is text I manually wrote on the page - inside the HTML file.

The text that does looks good, is loaded from an XML file and using the document.InnerHTML.GetElementById.. command.

Someone has an idia?

I've tried to change the position of the google link - no change..

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Assistant|Heebo&display=swap">
```

```css
body {
    background: #fdfdfe;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Assistant', sans-serif;
    color: #51565d; 
    line-height: 1.8;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: right;
    direction: rtl;
    overflow-y:scroll;
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code

```css
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Assistant&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"> 
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            background: #fdfdfe;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            font-family: 'Assistant', sans-serif;
            color: #51565d; 
            line-height: 1.8;
            height: 100%;
            text-align: right;
            direction: rtl;
            overflow-y:scroll;
            font-size: 16px;
        }
    </style>
```

```html
    <div class="">lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
```